# Stretch iOS background image

Tags: ios, png

How do I stretch a PNG to fit the entire 4" screen. My background image fits the 3.5" screen perfectly but is too small to fit the new 4" screen. (Oddly enough it fits the 3.5" screen exactly.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following UIImage method will let you create a new UIImage that you can use to make an image that will stretch:

```
- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets resizingMode:(UIImageResizingMode)resizingMode
```

For the `resizingMode` parameter you'll want to specify `UIImageResizingModeStretch`, and it will make your image stretch. So you could do it like the following:

```
UIImage *stretchableBackground = [background resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
```

Set that image as your background image, and it should stretch properly.

A better solution however would be to have a separate image for 4 inch screens that won't need to be stretched, because the image won't look as good when stretched.

Answer (score 2):

If you are wishing to keep the current aspect ratio then you should use the `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` attribute. This will fill the screen but not distort the imageView.

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Otherwise use a `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`.

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```